# Ideals and commutative rings

Tags: abstract-algebra

I am having a problem with;

Let $R$ be a commutative ring. Prove for ideals $I,J$ of $R$ that the following two conditions are equivalent:

(a) the function $R\to R/I\times R/J$ given by $x\mapsto (x+I,x+J)$ is surjective

(b)$R=I+J.$

Can I get any hints.

Comment: I have problems with starting it. if I assume (b) do these ideals have more than 0 in common? can it be that they include each other? with (a) I have problems to see how this function works. I was trying to make simple examples to illustrate the function but without any success. @DanZimm

Comment: What does the notation $I + J$ stand for? Just making sure I understand the question correctly!

Answer (score 3):

Hint: Show that (a) and (b) are equivalent to

(c) The element $(1,0)$ is in the image of the map $R \to R/I \times R/J$, i.e. there is an element $x \in R$ with $x \equiv 1 \pmod I$, $x \equiv 0 \pmod J$